# hdparm -tT /dev/sda Grab result into variable

Tags: linux, variables, division

Ok I am trying to find a way I can run

```
hdparm -t /dev/sda
```

10 time and grab the output and get an average result.

This does not give me what I am looking for: Can't figure out how to grab just the MB/sec

```
counter=1
total=''
average=''
while [ $counter -le 10 ] 
do 
 echo " "
 echo -n "SD Card Read Cache Test: $counter"
 output=$(sudo hdparm -T /dev/mmcblk0 )
 echo " "
 total=$total+$output
 ((counter++))
done
average=$((total/10))
echo $average
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the only problem you have:

```
output=$(sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda 2>&1 | sed -e '/Timing buffered/ s/.*= *\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/ p; d')
```

Comment: when I echo $output it is blank

Comment: sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda 2>&1 outputs /dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 106 MB in  3.01 seconds =  35.22 MB/sec
 and I just want the 35.22

Comment: When I run the command I gave, `echo $output` gives me `126.48`. Perhaps there is more than one space after the = sign? Try changing `s/.*= \(` to `s/.*= *\(`

Comment: That fixed it by adding in the *. Thanks!, I will mark as Answer, if you can edit it fo others. :)